# Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration

Tags: velocity

I work under linux,
in my application I limited the permission and all path will be read only

in my application I used **velocity-1.6.2.jar** and each time when it be called it create  **velocity.log** and this file should be read/write.

for this problem I try to disable velocity log

I try to add this line in **velocity properties**:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem
```

but I have this error :

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:206)
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:255)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:795)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:250)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:114)
org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:79)
```

this is the file **velocity properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.    

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# R U N T I M E  L O G
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  default LogChute to use: default: AvalonLogChute, Log4JLogChute, CommonsLogLogChute, ServletLogChute, JdkLogChute
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.JdkLogChute

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is the location of the Velocity Runtime log.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.log = velocity.log

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This controls whether invalid references are logged.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.log.invalid.references = true

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T E M P L A T E  E N C O D I N G
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

input.encoding=ISO-8859-1
output.encoding=ISO-8859-1

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# F O R E A C H  P R O P E R T I E S
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These properties control how the counter is accessed in the #foreach
# directive. By default the reference $velocityCount and $velocityHasNext
# will be available in the body of the #foreach directive.
# The default starting value for $velocityCount is 1.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

directive.foreach.counter.name = velocityCount
directive.foreach.counter.initial.value = 1
directive.foreach.maxloops = -1

directive.foreach.iterator.name = velocityHasNext

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# S E T  P R O P E R T I E S
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These properties control the behavior of #set.
# For compatibility, the default behavior is to disallow setting a reference
# to null.  This default may be changed in a future version.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

directive.set.null.allowed = false

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# I N C L U D E  P R O P E R T I E S
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# These are the properties that governed the way #include'd content
# is governed.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

directive.include.output.errormsg.start = <!-- include error :
directive.include.output.errormsg.end   =  see error log -->

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# P A R S E  P R O P E R T I E S
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

directive.parse.max.depth = 10

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# T E M P L A T E  L O A D E R S
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource.loader = file

file.resource.loader.description = Velocity File Resource Loader
file.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path = .
file.resource.loader.cache = false
file.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 2

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VELOCIMACRO PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# global : name of default global library.  It is expected to be in the regular
# template path.  You may remove it (either the file or this property) if
# you wish with no harm.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# velocimacro.library = VM_global_library.vm

velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline = true
velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.to.replace.global = false
velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.local.scope = false

velocimacro.context.localscope = false
velocimacro.max.depth = 20

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VELOCIMACRO STRICT MODE
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# if true, will throw an exception for incorrect number 
# of arguments.  false by default (for backwards compatibility)
# but this option will eventually be removed and will always
# act as if true
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
velocimacro.arguments.strict = false

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STRICT REFERENCE MODE
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# if true, will throw a MethodInvocationException for references
# that are not defined in the context, or have not been defined
# with a #set directive. This setting will also throw an exception
# if an attempt is made to call a non-existing property on an object
# or if the object is null.  When this property is true then property
# 'directive.set.null.allowed' is also set to true.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
runtime.references.strict = false

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# INTERPOLATION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# turn off and on interpolation of references and directives in string
# literals.  ON by default :)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
runtime.interpolate.string.literals = true


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE MANAGEMENT
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allows alternative ResourceManager and ResourceCache implementations
# to be plugged in.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
resource.manager.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl
resource.manager.cache.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceCacheImpl

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PARSER POOL
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Selects a custom factory class for the parser pool.  Must implement
# ParserPool.  parser.pool.size is used by the default implementation
# ParserPoolImpl
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

parser.pool.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.ParserPoolImpl
parser.pool.size = 20


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EVENT HANDLER
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allows alternative event handlers to be plugged in.  Note that each
# class property is actually a comma-separated list of classes (which will
# be called in order).
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class =
# eventhandler.nullset.class =
# eventhandler.methodexception.class =
# eventhandler.include.class =


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EVALUATE
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Evaluate VTL dynamically in template.  Select a class for the Context
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

directive.evaluate.context.class = org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PLUGGABLE INTROSPECTOR
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allows alternative introspection and all that can of worms brings.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

runtime.introspector.uberspect = org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SECURE INTROSPECTOR
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If selected, prohibits methods in certain classes and packages from being 
# accessed.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

introspector.restrict.packages = java.lang.reflect

# The two most dangerous classes

introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Class
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ClassLoader

# Restrict these for extra safety

introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Compiler
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.InheritableThreadLocal
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Package
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Process
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Runtime
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.RuntimePermission
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.SecurityManager
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.System
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Thread
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ThreadGroup
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ThreadLocal


runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem
```

**Updated :**

I try also to comment other line in **velocity properties**

```
#runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.AvalonLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.ServletLogChute,org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.JdkLogChute
```

but I have other error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1103)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1086)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1199)
org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1165)
org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.evaluate(Velocity.java:191)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using NullLogSystem which is a [Deprecated class](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/NullLogSystem.html), if you really want

> Logger used in case of failure. Does nothing.

Use [org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogChute](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/NullLogChute.html), in `velocity.properties`:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogChute
```

Or, this property can be set programmatically on your instance of VelocityEngine:

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", NullLogChute.class.getName());
```

Also see [dependencies](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.6.2/dependencies.html) for velocity 1.6.2 and check you have relevant versions.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works by changing the dependency to the most current one:

Before:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

After:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```